# Command for swap info in HPUX itanium and HPUX PARISC?

Tags: linux, hp-ux

I need to get commands for `swap information` in HPUX (both Itanium and PARISC).

Comment: You might consider submitting this question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link to [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23409/command-for-swap-info-in-hpux-itanium-and-hpux-parisc) that helped me. Thanks @Jonathan

```
/usr/sbin/swapinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

If by swap you mean copy information from one to another, you should consider [pax](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/upax.htm).